# Oscillatory electrical system using a chain of neurons

Tags: neuroscience, neurotransmitter, memory, action-potential, microarray

Many daily activities that we perform are result of inbuilt oscillatory circuits in our body. For example walking, breathing, heart beat, blinking, etc. The coding and decoding of stored memory also happen via controlled oscillations. The link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_oscillation contains information about neural oscillations. It says in here that a single neuron, an ensemble of neurons and activity of brain may exhibit synchronised oscillations. It is also said that these oscillatory circuits can control all the parameters of oscillations i.e. frequency, phase and amplitude.While above are true for neurons as a part of bigger systems, my question is related to study of isolated neurons.
There are many instances of studies of artificial neural circuitary created on a customized substrate(Micro Electrode Array) by masking techniques. Also there are loads of ongoing research to study the simple neural circuits in temporal and spatial domain by electrical interfacing of semiconductor and nerve cells using Field Effect Transistor(FET).

I want to know if these kind of oscillations are unique to some special kinds of neuron? Is the control of oscillation parameter possible in every neurons and isolated neurons? Can a neuron or any other cell exhibit change in action potential independently? Do other cells except neuron and pacemaker cells exhibit oscillation? Can a single neuron exhibit memory?
Can a simple circuit like below generate oscillations?
Suppose I culture the neurons on a substrate in a controlled way such that one neuron is connected to only one other neuron in a linear fashion and the last neuron is connected to first. Assuming we supply the ions if there is loss, can a clock pulse of varying frequencies be generated, where the frequency is the function of the no. of intermediate neurons and their length.

It would be a great help if somebody can provide information about softwares to simulate simple neural circuits (If available).

Comment: What is your analysis on this? Theoretically you can build a continuously oscillating system but there will always be some loss. If the neuron never runs out of energy then it would keep firing. The period of the oscillation and the nature of the steady states depend on system parameters. Your question is broad and you have not made any effort to find an answer to the question. Therefore I am voting to close this.

Comment: Agreed with @WYSIWYG - No neuron ever evolved to live like a bacterium. This is too theoretical and probably more suitable for another more theoretical SE site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too theoretical for Biology.SE

Comment: ps - I ran a few searches on Scholar and there is really nothing to be found (search terms autostimulation&neuron, self-wired neuron and the likes).

Comment: @AliceD FHN model is continuously oscillating system.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - yes, but it is a model not applicable to a biological system. That is my issue with this question.

Comment: @AliceD yeah.. This case has to be specifically modelled.

Comment: I wanted to know about generating clock pulse using neurons by giving its own signal as feedback

Comment: Suppose for example I culture the neurons on a substrate in a controlled way such that one neuron is connected to only one other neuron in a linear fashion and the last neuron is connected to first. Assuming we supply the ions if there is loss, can a clock pulse of varying frequencies can be generated, where the frequency depends on the no. of intermediate neurons

Comment: Interesting add @DivyaPrakash, I retracted my close vote.

Comment: single neurons can act as oscillators without the need for feedback, simply by the interplay between various channels.

Comment: @AliceD please, can you explain more? If possible give the answer to my question too.

Comment: I vote to re-open this (edited) question. At least there are some theoretical studies on such systems, and also relation to how such constructions can't explain the scalar property.

Comment: Original poster (question author) did not provide any evidence of even basic research, using google, or pubmed, or google scholar. Hence, it should be closed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not provide any work on answering question. This might be asked in chat room, rather than Bio@SE. Although, I might be wrong

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**
A single pacemaker neuron can generate oscillatory behavior.

**Background**
Given our exchange in the comments, I will focus on *single neurons with intrinsic oscillatory behavior*. For example, thalamocortical relay neurons and inferior olive neurons have intrinsic oscillatory properties, mainly through the interaction of a hyperpolarization-activated cation current (I<sub>h</sub>) and a low-threshold activated Ca<sup>2+</sup> current (I<sub>T</sub>) ([McCormick & Huguenard, 1992](http://jn.physiology.org/content/68/4/1384.full-text.pdf+html), and Fig. 1).

[image: Model for an oscillatory inferior olive neuron]
<sup>Fig. 1 Model for an oscillatory inferior olive neuron. Source: [Bal & McCormick (1997)](http://jn.physiology.org/content/77/6/3145)</sup>

Rhythmic burst firing is created through generation of a low-threshold Ca<sup>2+</sup> current (I<sub>T</sub>), which activates fast action potentials mediated by Na<sup>+</sup>, K<sup>+</sup>, and Ca<sup>2+</sup> currents (I<sub>Na</sub>, I<sub>K</sub>, and I<sub>Ca</sub>, respectively). Entry of Ca<sup>2+</sup> in the cell during fast action-potential firing and low-threshold Ca<sup>2+</sup> spiking result in after-hyperpolarization through activation of a Ca<sup>2+</sup>-activated K<sup>+</sup> current. This afterhyperpolarization activates I<sub>h</sub>. Combined activation of I<sub>h</sub> and decrease of a Ca<sup>2+</sup> activated K<sup>+</sup> current (I<sub>K,Ca</sub>) results in depolarization of neuron, which activates another low-threshold Ca<sup>2+</sup> spike. In this manner, I<sub>h</sub> modulates frequency of oscillation. In addition, tonic activation of I<sub>h</sub> also contributes to average membrane potential, and therefore to presence, strength, and frequency of oscillation
in these neurons.

Regarding the series of sub-questions - these are quite varied. Perhaps it is better to generate another one or two focused, well-formulated questions on this. For now, I will answer them curtly below. Further, the papers I linked contain a wealth of information, and the [McCormick & Huguenard (1992)](http://jn.physiology.org/content/68/4/1384.full-text.pdf+html) paper is a detailed modeling study. Both papers are awesome and the authors are three of my all-time favorites so far.

`I want to know if these kind of oscillations are unique to some special kinds of neuron?`
**Answer**: Yes quite unique, because I<sub>h</sub> channels are quite unique (they have been called "funny currents") and they are not present in every cell.

`Is the control of oscillation parameter possible in every neurons and isolated neurons?`
**Answer**: No, as the molecular machinery such as I<sub>h</sub> channels may be lacking in most other cells.

`Can a neuron or any other cell exhibit change in action potential independently?`
**Answer**: That depends whether the cells are coupled through synapses or other means.

`Do other cells except neuron and pacemaker cells exhibit oscillation?`
**Answer**: Yes, some cells start to oscillate, for example in the degenerated retina (modeling work only) and there are non-neural cells that when cultured spontaneously start to oscillate.

`Can a single neuron exhibit memory?`
**Answer**: Yes, through long-term potentiation or depression.

**References**
- [Bal & McCormick, *J Neurophysiol* (1997); **77**:3145-56](http://jn.physiology.org/content/77/6/3145)
- [McCormick & Huguenard, *J Neurophysiol* (1992), **68**(4): 1384-1400](http://jn.physiology.org/content/68/4/1384.full-text.pdf+html)